# Regex to convert spaces into commas

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file with below data

```
Name        Id    Contact        Email
raj       3232    408333       ra@gmail.com
anu      353453   409242       anu@yahoomail.com
```

I want to replace the above file with below data.

```
Name,Id,Contact,Email
raj,3232,408333,ra@gmail.com
anu,353453,409242,anu@yahoomail.com
```

Replace all the spaces in a line with commas and ignore the spaces between each new line. How can I achieve this ??

I read online that `$value =~ s/\s+/,/g;` would convert all the spaces and tabs in a line and replace it with a comma. but it doesn't execute that way.

Can someone advise please??

Here is my exact code. It might confuse a bit. but here it is. The file gets copied in a array, then changes made to array as per needed. Once changes are made, the array is written back to the file.

```
open(FILE, $filename) || die "File not found";
my @lines = <FILE>;
close(FILE);

my @newlines;
foreach(@lines) {
            $_ =~ tr/ \t/,/s;       
            push(@newlines,$_);  
}


open(my $fh, '>', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
print $fh @newlines;
close($fh);
```

}

Comment: `\s` matches any whitespace including a normal space. Try `$value =~ s/[ \t]+/,/g;` or `$value =~ s/\h+/,/g;`.

Comment: @stribizhev- this didnt work. this one will only remove tabs.

Comment: Then you must show your exact code. Also, above, I meant to say *including a carriage return and line feed characters*.

Comment: This more simple to do it with awk.

Comment: @stribizhev- edited my post with exact code. i am passing the file data to an array and making changes to the array. is it the reason regex not working ?

Comment: The premise is a bad idea. Though it's uncommon, email addresses may contain spaces so long as they're quoted.  Since your incoming data seems to be fixed-width, unpack it into fields, and then use Text::CSV to produce safe CSV with it. If your input data isn't fixed width, and is really only space delimited, it's broken before you even write a line of code.

Comment: There is **absolutely** no need to read the entire file into memory (twice!) in order to make the changes. Just do it in-place, save some memory, and make the code simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it without a regex:

```
$value =~ tr/ \t/,/s;
```

`tr///` is documented in [`perldoc perlop`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlop#tr-SEARCHLIST-REPLACEMENTLIST-cdsr) (or `perldoc -f tr` if your perldoc is new enough).

Comment: @Ayesha "didn't work" is not a problem description. What did it do? What did you expect instead?

Comment: @melpomene- updated the post with the exact code. i think the problem is that i am writing it to an array first and then manipulating the array. ?

Comment: @melpomene- i mentioned in the start of the post. a file has spaces between each words. i need to replace those spaces and use a comma instead of those spaces.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89429/discussion-between-melpomene-and-ayesha).

Comment: @melpomene- this works well. athough i had to write to a different file as suggested by you in the chat

Answer (score 0):

To do this on the terminal you can just do this:

```
perl -pe 'tr/ /,/s' datafile.txt
```

To replace the original file with the changed version, just add an i option:

```
perl -pi -e 'tr/ /,/s' datafile.txt
```

**Output:**

```
$ perl -pe 'tr/ /,/s' datafile.txt 
Name,Id,Contact,Email
raj,3232,408333,ra@gmail.com
anu,353453,409242,anu@yahoomail.com
$
```

.

```
$ perl -pi -e 'tr/ /,/s' datafile.txt 
$ more datafile.txt 
Name,Id,Contact,Email
raj,3232,408333,ra@gmail.com
anu,353453,409242,anu@yahoomail.com
$
```